# How to find out on which core a thread is running on?

Tags: process, cpu, proc, multithreading, thread

Let's say we have a CPU-intensive application called `multi-threaded-application.out` that is running on top of Ubuntu with a PID of 10000. It has 4 threads with tid 10001, 10002, 10003, and 10004. I want to know, at any given time, on which core each of these threads is being scheduled?

I tried `/proc/<pid>/tasks/<tid>/status`, but I couldn't find any information regarding the core ID that is responsible for running the given thread.

This question is somehow related [to this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607892/how-to-get-number-of-threads-tasks-per-core-in-linux).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032372/how-can-i-see-which-cpu-core-a-thread-is-running-in perhaps ?  "To get the information you want, look in /proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/status. The third field will be an 'R' if the thread is running. The sixth from the last field will be the core the thread is currently running on, or the core it last ran on (or was migrated to) if it's not currently running."

Comment: @steve The output of proc status is different than what's mentioned in that question. DavidSchwartz himself mentioned in the heading that "The answer below is no longer accurate as of 2014"

Comment: I am afraid that unless its CPU0 and have designed strict CPU isolation (which if it was proven interesting is almost impossible to achieve... (on a working system I mean...)) the command you would issue might well change scheduler's mind at once! (Look at your count of rescheduling interrupts! ;-) )

Comment: @MC68020 very interesting point!

Answer (score 0):

The following command did the trick:

```
ps -mo pid,tid,%cpu,psr -p <main process ID>
```

Options explained:

- `-m` - show threads after processes
- `-o` - user-defined format, showing process ID, "the unique number representing a dispatchable entity" (thread ID), CPU utilization, and the processor the process is *currently* assigned to
- `-p` for the given process ID

The above pertain to Linux `ps` only and will not work on macOS/BSD.

Comment: I'll assume the responsibility of downvoting this answer. The OP writes about some 4-threaded "CPU-intensive application". If I assume that the 4 threads are more or less equally sharing the responsibility of the load then it is very unlikely that issuing the above command several times consecutively will provide identical results. On a standard non cpu isolated env, the only reason for successive occurrences of this command to produce identical results would be that all tasks involved are mainly idle.

Comment: Apologizes : To read "all CPUs involved are mainly idle" instead of "all tasks involved are mainly iddle" in the above comment.

Comment: As stated in some comment I made as part of OP's question, do consider the number of rescheduling interrupts. It simply tells the number of times the scheduler has believed pertinent to switch some thread from one CPU to another one.

Comment: Of course, it's not providing an identical result, because a thread migrates several times during its lifetime. What's wrong with it? I've tested and the output exactly matches the number of CPU migrations reported by `perf`.

Answer (score 0):

using `top` if you hit `h` to get the help menu, it will explain...

- `F` for fields
- the ones with `*` are what are marked as to be displayed
- look for `P` which is *Last Used CPU (SMP)*

  - use the down arrow key on keyboard to move the highlight down to `P` then hit spacebar to put a `*` to it
- hit escape to go back to the running top display, notice the new `P` column that will correspond to cpu core number
- `H` to toggle *threads* on/off
- `s` to update display delay, I like 1 sec versus the default 3, do 0.1 if you prefer
- `i`  to toggle idle processes on/off; `u` to filter on user; `o` to customize filter
- `W` to save this top configuration so the `P` column shows from now on when you run top.

Comment: Could you please explain how (apart from precise cpu isolation) launching top would not immediately trigger some change in the distribution and therefore offer some picture more or less radically different to the situation where top was not running ?

Comment: no, i cannot explain, other than what is described from the `top` help menu.  `top` will display processes jumping to different `P` core numbers, thats all i know in regards to that

Comment: Of course you cannot. Nobody could. My point here is the same I tried to express in comments of OP' question & answer : Exactly the same with benchmarks. (But top is even worse to that respect) Whatever you launch will actually modify the picture you wanted. Anyway… since OP apparently does not care… let it be. However, I'd be personally happy to upvote your answer provided you include some suggestion to pin top on some core excluded from the list of cores made available to the application to watch. Then, the more core you get, the less pollution you'll get.

Comment: As a proof regarding (h)top polluting the desired result (which core being used by some thread) just launch the multithreaded cpu-bound application and observe the rate of rescheduling interrupts, then launch (h)top… and observe the rate of these interrupts… what can you deduce ?

Comment: processes will jump all other the place on cores as normal behavior unless some kind of cpu affinity is applied.  I observe this all the time running commercial software and top shows just fine some *N* number of processes/threads of that all having a consistent cpu (core) number under top's P column since it was started.  As for *getting which core a thread is running on* one could use top with `--batch`  and `-n 1` however often via cron and then parse that output for what `P` core number whatever pid was running on when and see how it jumps around.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html    *The top program provides a dynamic real-time view of a running system.  It can display system summary information as well as a list of processes or threads currently being managed by the Linux kernel.*

Comment: you seem to be insinuating that if I run `top` that it displaces the processes you wish to find out what core they were running on, which it very well could (unless cpu affinity) is in play.  And you can observe `top` change core numbers as well as it runs and is displaying, that's what the kernel does managing processes.  But how is your `ps` command immune to that how can you prove your use of the `ps` command doesn't *pollute* as well?

Comment: OK, let's forget it. BTW, there is nothing such as *"my ps command"*, I never suggested it would not pollute as well, please see my (now old) comments on the answer recommending its use.